# Observer design pattern - Subscribing to specific notification type

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

Firstly, I apologise if this has been covered previously. My search attempted came up with nothing so please point me in the right direction if I've missed something obvious. I've explored other patterns, such as Mediator, but didn't come to a conclusion that I thought was "correct"

The context:
I'm authoring a WP plugin that uses the save_post, user_create and remove_user hooks. Using the Observer pattern I'd like to notify subscribers when a hook is triggered.

My question:
I'm attempting to use the Observer pattern to notify subscribers if they subscribe to a specific notification type. Is there a pattern/best practice that covers this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) concept.

Comment: Would you happen to know if I'd be correct in thinking this is essentially Observer, but it allows you to identify the source of the notification?

If my understanding is correct it look's spot on. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Yes, it's essentially just a collection of Observers. It's key strength is mass/selective publication to subscribers.